# reset data after calling notifyDataSetChanged in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, static-members

I am using static array which I am passing to listview from async task and there is a search bar in that activity so when the user types in search the results are displayed as required as notifyDataSetChanged is called accordingly.

But there is one state when the search results are displayed and user presses back button...in this state because of this the array is reset to number of elements is search results and when the activity is loaded then only those elements are displayed.

How this can be solved.
Should i avoid static array to listview?
can anyone help?

Comment: keep another array and set that array according to the search result and when there is no text in search bar, populate listview with original array

Comment: I have tried this but no success.

Comment: please find the code [here](http://pastebin.com/zBmwAh2u)
async task is in Activity.